# Cordova Apps with Visual Studio VS-TAC Error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

I installed VS 2015 with Cordova and everything looks good, but when i want to runt he app with the simulator I get this errormessage in Visual Stuido

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Error installing local npm package. demo    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets   279
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BLD401  Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\mathis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.    demo        1

i already tried to install vs-tac with npm but i get this error in the cmd window:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9XOg.png)

Comment: I have the same issue, followed the solution in this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f97d8c5-6069-49ee-a065-283741fd483f/unable-to-build-my-first-cordova-app-in-vs-2015?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova But no luck... looks like the -g global install switch is not working correctly, I am going to guess that environment variables are missing, but not sure what variables might be needed

Comment: This could be an issue with the version of Node that you have installed. We made some changes in Update 6 of Visual Studio TACO so that the tools can use a private copy of Node and it may fix this issue for you: http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/04/announcing-update-6.html